# Attribute error when generating random numbers in Python

Tags: python, datetime, random

I asked a similar question regarding this same piece of code earlier but once again I have found myself stuck. Particularly on the generation of a license plate containing two letters, two numbers, and then two letters. I hope that this question isn't a duplicate but in this circumstance I am very stuck with what to do, this is the code so far and I hope you can identify where I am going wrong:

```
from datetime import date, datetime, time, timedelta
import time, string
from random import uniform, random

def timeDelta():
    print("Average Speed Checker")
    start = (input("Car has passed Cam1: "))
    licensePlate = str(firstLetters + randomNumber + " " + secondLetters)
    print(licensePlate)
    if start in ("y"):
        camInput1 = datetime.now()
        print(camInput1)
        print("Car is travelling...")
        time.sleep(1)
        print("Car is travelling...")
        time.sleep(1)
        print("Car has passed cam2")
        camInput2 = camInput1 + timedelta(seconds = uniform(5, 10))
        timeDelta = camInput2 - camInput1
        distance = 200
        duration = timeDelta.total_seconds()
        print("Time Delta is equal to: {0}".format(duration))
        speedCarMs = distance/duration
        print("Car is travelling in m/s at: {0}".format(speedCarMs))
        speedCarMph = 2.237*speedCarMs
        print("Car is travelling in MPH at: {0}".format(speedCarMph))
        if speedCarMph > 60:
            fileInput:

def possibleNumber():
    possibleNumbers = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0)
    randomNumber = random.sample(possibleNumbers, 2)

def randomLetters1(y):
    return ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase) for x in             range(y))
firstLetters = (randomLetters1(2))
secondLetters = (randomLetters1(3))

print("Choose which function you want to use: ")
while True:
    answer = (input("Choice: "))
    if answer in ("speed"):
        timeDelta()
else:
    print("Invalid response")
```

According to python, the issue is to do with this:

```
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'choice'
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You did not import the `random` module. You imported the `random.random()` **function**:

```
from random import uniform, random
```

If you wanted to use `choice()` and `sample()` as well, import that in addition:

```
from random import uniform, random, choice, sample
```

and adjust your use of those functions:

```
def possibleNumber():
    possibleNumbers = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0)
    randomNumber = sample(possibleNumbers, 2)

def randomLetters1(y):
    return ''.join(choice(string.ascii_uppercase) for x in range(y))
```

Or, instead, import *just the module*:

```
import random
```

and your code will work as you don't actually *use* `random()` anywhere, provided you replace `uniform()` with `random.uniform()`:

```
camInput2 = camInput1 + timedelta(seconds = random.uniform(5, 10))
```

I'll reiterate again that you don't need to create `camInput2`, as `camInput1 + some_timedelta - camInput1` produces the same value as `some_timedelta`; you can just use:

```
timeDelta = timedelta(seconds = random.uniform(5, 10))
```

You never call the `randomNumbers()` function, nor does the function *return* anything. The `randomNumber` local name in that function is not available outside of the function.

Have the function return the result and use the function where you now try to use the result via the `randomNumber` name:

```
def possibleNumber():
    possibleNumbers = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0)
    return random.sample(possibleNumbers, 2)
```

and

```
licensePlate = str(firstLetters + possibleNumber() + " " + secondLetters)
```

Comment: I did use `uniform()`  But thanks for the response, now I am being told that `randomNumber` is not defined?

Comment: @TooLateTheHero: `randomNumber` is just a local variable in the `possibleNumber()` function, not a global. It is not available outside the function. Why not use `return` and store the result?

Comment: Sorry to bother you, but I am not entirely familiar with the use of `return`, could you help me put it into place? I understand what you mean, I just can't see how I'd put it into my code, thanks.

Comment: @TooLateTheHero: I included a sample already of how to do it; it's no different from your `randomLetters1()` function.

Comment: Sorry, I'vee tried but I am really stuck as sample uses a population and I just can't see how I can implement it.

Answer (score 1):

`random.random`, which you refer to in your code as simply `random`, because you imported it directly into your namespace (`from random import ... random`) instead of importing the entire module (`import random`), is a free function, which does not have an attribute named `choice`.

For the code you've written, calling `random.choice`, and `random.sample`, your import statement should be `import random`. Alternatively, switch your function calls to simply `choice(...)` and `sample(...)`...

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same issue when one day my code stopped working because of this same error. 
Reading the other answers i came up with this workaround:
Give an alias to the random module, so that when you call the alias.choice method there is no ambiguity:

```
import json,random as rd, string
from random import uniform, random, choice, sample

def randomString(stringLength):
    letters = string.ascii_letters
    return ''.join(rd.choice(letters) for i in range(stringLength))
```