# random.choice() is not working for some reason

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

For some reason when I try to use random.choice() it just doesn't work and shows me this error I am trying to make a command for my bot

```
Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'choice'
```

```
import random

Rev = random.choice(Rev_list)
Rev = str(Rev)
Rev_better = Rev.replace('Cats' ,person)
Rev_better = Rev_better.replace("Cats," ,person)
Rev_better = Rev_better.replace("cats", person)
Rev_better = Rev_better.replace("film", "person")
Rev_better = Rev_better.replace("movie", "person")
await ctx.send(Rev_better)
```

Comment: Please share all your code. Something is missing. Did you overwrite random somewhere?

Comment: can you add more information about your code?

Comment: Have you done anything like `random = ...` in your code? Please post an [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), you have not posted code that anyone can run. And the error is likely in the missing parts.

Comment: Did you maybe after `import random` also do `from random import random`? As that would give you this exact error https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28353800/attribute-error-when-generating-random-numbers-in-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following

```
import random
print(random.choice([1, 2, 3]))
from random import random
print(random.choice([1, 2, 3]))
```

which succeeds on line 2 but then fails on line 4 with

> AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'choice'

the reason is because you bind the name `random` to the module but then after that you bind the same name `random` to the function inside that module `random()`. This function does not have a method called `choice` hence the error.

I strongly suspect that in the code you've left off from your question, you have `from random import random` which is the cause of you error.

Comment: Thanks for your help, turns out I did something similar to `from random import` which caused the errors

Comment: No problem, for future reference this is why you need to test that the example you post in your question actually replicates the error. This way you won't accidentally leave off the line that is the actual cause.